# unable to connect to centos server

Tags: linux

I have restarted the network service in my new server. After that I m not able to reach the server directly through putty. It keeps timing out.
I am able to connect to server via ssh from any of the server in the same network.

Comment: can you ping the server?

Comment: I'm not understanding the problem here... You can connect to it from other servers in the same subnet, but not from where exactly, a remote computer? That would be a network or router issue, or is the problem something different?

Comment: I was able to connect directly to server from putty until I restarted network service. After that  my connection to server was aborted and I could nt connect to server from putty anymore

Comment: This is a remote server. I am not able to ping the server also. I dont understand what could be wrong

Comment: I am getting connection timeout error in putty. This was reachable directly till   the time i restarted the network service

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/660571/putty-login-error-through-ssh-network-error-connenction-timeout issue is very similar to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out that the default gateway was missing in the server somehow which I am not sure how.
Adding a default route entry using the command

```
route add default gw IP_address eth0
```

resolved my issue. 
My server is reachable directly via putty and I am able to ping the server also.